# How to select dropdownlist values of particular text value which is in ng-repeat and ng-model in angularjs and how can we post it to database

Tags: html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm pretty new to angularjs.So,please kindly ignore if there are any errors.Here I have one dropdownlist within ng-repeat if I select the values in dropdownlist the corresponding Item code and the selected description from dropdownlist should pass to angularcontroller and I need to post it to the mvc controller

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope',function ($scope, $http,$rootScope) {
    $scope.values = [{

        Code: 1,

        Description: 'Apple'
       

    }, {

        Code: 2,

         Description: 'Orange'

    }, {

        Code: 3,

         Description: 'Mango'

    }, {

        COde: 4,

         Description: 'Guva'

    }
    ];



   

    $scope.ddlrhs = '';

    $scope.data = [{

        Code: 1,

         Description: 'Red'

    }, {

        Code: 2,

         Description: 'Orange'

    }, {

        Code: 3,

         Description: 'Yellow'

    }, {

        Code: 4,

         Description: 'Green'

    }
    ];
      $scope.submit = function ()
    {
       
      
       $scope.list = [];
     
       
       
        for (var i = 0; i < $scope.values.length; i++) {
            var j = "";
            $scope.list.push({
                VALUE: $scope.values[i].Code,
                Description: $scope.myForm.items[i].Description
               
            })
        }
       
        $http({
            method: "POST",
            url: "/Controller/Save",
            data: 
                 $scope.list
               
        })
    }


}])
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div id="dvcollection" ng-App="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl" >
        <form name="myForm" >
            <table id="tblcollections">

                <thead>
                    <tr >
                        <th>ItemCode</th>
                        <th>ItemDesc</th>
                        <th>DropdownDesc</th>
                        <th>DropdownCode</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="item in values">
                        <td><span>{{item.Code}}</span> </td>

                        <td>{{item.Description}}</td>

                        <td>
                            <select ng-model="myForm.items[$index]" ng-options=" element.Description  for element in data ">

                                <option value="">Select </option>
                            </select>
                            
                        </td>
                        <td><span>{{myForm.items[$index].Code}}</span></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>
                            <input type="button" value="save" ng-click="submit()"style="float:right;" >

                        </td>

                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </form>
    </div>
```

Comment: I think you should first declare **$scope.items = [];** then replace all **myForm.items** with **items**

Comment: are you trying to map the variables like **one to one**

Comment: No,I'm not trying to map one to one,for the selected value from dropdownlist I need the corresponding item code which should be passed to angular controller

Answer (score 0):

Hey May be this might be your expectation

```
<div ng-app="myApp" >  
<div id="dvcollection" ng-controller="ctrl">
  <form name="myForm">
    <table id="tblcollections">

      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ItemCode</th>
          <th>ItemDesc</th>
          <th>DropdownDesc</th>
          <th>DropdownCode</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="item in values">
          <td><span>{{item.Code}}</span> </td>

          <td>{{item.Description}}</td>
          <td>
            <select ng-model="itemssample" ng-options=" element.Description for element in data " ng-change="pushingelement(item.Code,itemssample.Code)">

              <option value="">Select </option>
            </select>

          </td>
          <td><span>{{myForm.items[$index].Code}}</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td>
            <input type="button" value="save" ng-click="submit()" style="float:right;">

          </td>

        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>

  </form>
  <div> This is written to ensure that mapping is stored or not. (Not necessary)
    <p ng-repeat="item in list">
      Mapping of {{$index}} element {{item.ItemCode}} -> {{item.ColorCode}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Ensure that your MVC Controller should have a model as

```
public class MapperClass
{

    public int ItemCode { get; set; }
    public int ColorCode { get; set; }

}
```

**SCRIPT**

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('ctrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$rootScope', function ($scope, $http, $rootScope) {
      $scope.list = [];
      $scope.values = [
      { Code: 1, Description: 'Apple' },
      { Code: 2, Description: 'Orange' },
      { Code: 3, Description: 'Mango' },
      { Code: 4, Description: 'Guva' }
      ];

      $scope.ddlrhs = '';

      $scope.data = [
          { Code: 1, Description: 'Red' },
          { Code: 2, Description: 'Orange' },
          { Code: 3, Description: 'Yellow' },
          { Code: 4, Description: 'Green' }
      ];

      $scope.pushingelement = function (itemCode, colorCode) {
          var temp = { "ItemCode": itemCode, "ColorCode": colorCode };
          $scope.list.push(temp);
          console.log($scope.list);

      }
      $scope.submit = function () {
          $http({
              method: "POST",
              url: "/Controller/Save",
              data:
                  object:$scope.list

          })
      }
  }
  ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY ONCE I HOPE IT HELPS YOU

```html
 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>get selected value from dropdownlist in angularjs</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('sampleapp', [])
app.controller('samplecontrol', function ($scope) {
$scope.sample = [{
id: '1',
name: 'Red'
}, {
id: '2',
name: 'Green'
}, {
id: '3',
name: 'Orange'
}, {
id: '4',
name: 'Yellow'
}];
});
</script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="sampleapp" data-ng-controller="samplecontrol">
<form id="form1">
Select Name:
<select data-ng-model="ddlvalue">
<option value="">--Select--</option>
<option data-ng-repeat="t in sample" value="">{{t.name}}</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```